# Drop columns not in list intersection

Tags: python

I am trying to subset the columns of a dataset using `.intersection()`. The number of columns to keep is >30, leaving the current solution looking very long:

```
df_features = [remove1, remove2, remove3, keep1, keep2, keep3, keep4, ..., keep30]
keep_features = [keep1, keep2, keep3, ..., keep30]
df_keep = df[df.columns.intersection(keep_features)]
```

The above works, but I was wondering if there is a more succinct way to write it--equivalent to using `~` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop the columns too (assuming they are all inside the initial frame):

```py
df_keep = df.drop(columns=remove_features)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to instead use `.difference()`, which finds the symmetric difference between two lists. The syntax requires a change to specify the columns to remove:

```
remove_features = [remove1, remove2, remove3]
df_keep = df[df.columns.difference(remove_features)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below:

`df_keep = df[keep_features]`